# Dragging and dropping something onto an xna window?

Tags: drag-and-drop, xna, window

I have an XNA4 wndow set up and was wondering if I could get it to accept drag+drop actions, what I envision is someone grabs a jpeg and drags it into the window, upon release of the mouse an event is fired off with a string pointing to the jpeg.

Is this doable and if so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, here is a link to a tutorial on doing this with a windows form:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307966

and here is a link to a post about doing just this (answer is past a few posts saying that it's impossible):

http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/4020/20419.aspx

finally here is some code for ease of access (you need a reference to the System.Windows.Forms namespace):

```
protected override void Initialize()
{
    Form gameForm = (Form)Form.FromHandle(Window.Handle);
    gameForm.AllowDrop = true;
    gameForm.DragEnter += new DragEventHandler(gameForm_DragEnter);
    gameForm.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(gameForm_DragDrop);
}
```

Also, it seems it's possible to run a game inside a Form control as of XNA 2

Answer (score 0):

While I recognise that this is many years too late here is a direct link to a working demo.

The SLN might not want to autoload but you can just drop it into VS2013 and it will update it. I was getting a "licencing" popup when I tried to just run the SLN.

Hope this helps anyone who might still be working on this.

http://geekswithblogs.net/mikebmcl/archive/2011/03/27/drag-and-drop-in-a-windows-xna-game.aspx